# Storing values that are lists into database from dataframe using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to store values to mysql database that is a dataframe consisting of lists in every row.
Below is the dataframe:

```
0                    [Nissan Motor, Carlos Ghosn]
1                    [Nissan Motor, Carlos Ghosn]
2                                              []
3                              [David Muir, Trio]
4                                              []
5                                              []
6                                              []
```

Comment: Do you want comma-separated values to go in different columns or single column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
x = [["Nissan Motor", "Carlos Ghosn"], ["Nissan Motor", "Carlos Ghosn"], [], ["David Muir", "Trio"], [], [],[]]
df = pd.DataFrame({"data": x})

df.to_sql(con = "connection_string", name = "table_name", schema = "schema_name", if_exists="replace", dtype={'data': postgresql.JSONB}, index = False)
```

Reading it back:

```
q = "select * from schema.table_name"
df = pd.read_sql(q, con="connection_string")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                           data
0  [Nissan Motor, Carlos Ghosn]
1  [Nissan Motor, Carlos Ghosn]
2                            []
3            [David Muir, Trio]
4                            []
5                            []
6                            []
```

Used [JSONB](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB)